# Count pairs with given sum

Tags: c++, hashtable

Given an array of integers, and a number ‘sum’, find the number of pairs of integers in the array whose sum is equal to ‘sum’. This is the solution by [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-pairs-with-given-sum/):

```
// C++ implementation of simple method to find count of 
// pairs with given sum. 
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

// Returns number of pairs in arr[0..n-1] with sum equal 
// to 'sum' 
int getPairsCount(int arr[], int n, int sum) 
{ 
    unordered_map<int, int> m; 

    // Store counts of all elements in map m 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
        m[arr[i]]++; 

    int twice_count = 0; 

    // iterate through each element and increment the 
    // count (Notice that every pair is counted twice) 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    { 
        twice_count += m[sum-arr[i]]; 

        // if (arr[i], arr[i]) pair satisfies the condition, 
        // then we need to ensure that the count is 
        // decreased by one such that the (arr[i], arr[i]) 
        // pair is not considered 
        if (sum-arr[i] == arr[i]) 
            twice_count--; 
    } 

    // return the half of twice_count 
    return twice_count/2; 
} 

// Driver function to test the above function 
int main() 
{ 
    int arr[] = {1, 5, 7, -1, 5} ; 
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 
    int sum = 6; 
    cout << "Count of pairs is " 
         << getPairsCount(arr, n, sum); 
    return 0; 
}
```

My big question is, what is sum-arr? It is not declared, so it must be built in C++. However, I can't find any documentation of it and I am unsure on how it works.
I am trying to follow the code, and it doesn't make sense the sum-arr values.

arr [1,5,8,-1,5]

m [0,1,0,0,0]

sum-arr [5,1,-2,7,1]

Comment: `sum-arr[]` is just subtraction of two integers

Answer (score 3):

> Expression, `sum - arr[n]` which yields the value stored in the nth position of the array.

Here, the value of arr at n (here at the position where `i` points, since it is `arr[i]`) is subtracted with the value of `sum`.

Given, you say,

`int arr[] = { 1, 5 , 8, -1, 5 }`

and

`int sum = 6`

Then, for example, take  `i` as *0*...

`arr[i]` is represented as `arr[0]` which means pointing to the first element (0) in the array `arr`. Here, the value is 1.

And subtracting **1 from 6**, we get *5*.

On the other hand, `sum - arr` is the subtraction of an integer(`int`) with a pointer(`int arr[]` will become `int * arr` inside the program), which, in fact, is not possible, since a super-pointer is bigger than a sub-pointer...

However, you can do, `sum - *arr` (which is called dereferencing).

Last words,

Just to reduce all this confusion with using pointers and everything, just use `std::vector<type>`(**Example:** `std::vector<int> arr;`), which is a common practice in C++ and whats more, works just like them too! (**You are stuck to using pointers in C though!**).

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

> My big question is, what is sum-arr?

`sum` is an id-expression. It names a variable of type `int`.

`arr` is an id-expression. It names a different variable, which is of type `int*`. It is also a sub-expression of the expression `arr[i]`. That expression is the subscript operator, which in this case increments the pointer `arr` to its `i`'th successive sibling in the array and indirects the pointer.

`-` is the subtraction operator. `sum` expression is the left hand operand, and `arr[i]` is the right hand operand.